# How to display CMS block in my latest product page?

Tags: cms-block

I have my latest product page called in the file `latest.phtml`, I need to add a cms block in this page updating its `layout.xml`. Note that this is not a cms page. I want to put the block in the left sidebar.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `.xml` file of your related page say `latest.phtml` and add this code

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="cms/block" name="block_name">
     <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>Your_Block_id</block_id></action>
    </block> 
</reference>
```

Comment: How can i find the .xml file retaled to my phtml ? this file is inside my theme/template folder

Comment: does your `.phtml` file belong to any extension??

Comment: I think its part of my theme. My theme is legenda by smartwave and this file comes with it

Comment: in your `layout` folder do you have any file called `local.xml`

Comment: yes is the layout of my theme, my problem is how to connect a specific block to this page

Comment: if you have `local.xml` file just add the above code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19610/discussion-between-ylli-and-dh47).

Comment: or if you purchased that theme contact the support theme for assistance